# SQLiteDatabase skipping ahead?

Tags: android

Given the following code in my activity's onCreate:

```
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.logmenu);

        //DEBUG CODE
        new DBAdaptor(this).dropDatabase();

        if (!DBAdaptor.checkDataBase() ) {
            showDialog(DIALOG_NO_DB);
        }


        seasonSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.seasonspinner);

        List<String> seasons = new ArrayList<String>(); 
        SQLiteDatabase db = new DBAdaptor(this).getReadableDatabase();


       /* //Select _key FROM seasons;
        Cursor results = db.query("seasons", new String[] {"_key"}, null, null, null, null, null);
        results.moveToFirst();
        do {
            String season = results.getString(results.getColumnIndex("_key"));
            seasons.add(season);
        } while (results.moveToNext());*/
```

If I run that as shown, with the section populating the spinner commented out, the following happens:

1. The view renders. Invisibly, the database from the last run is deleted so that the next check will fail
2. A dialog pops up asking if I want to initialize the database. I click yes.
3. The database init runs (involving communication with a remote server)
4. The database is now populated and ready for use
5. Control returns to this view, with the empty spinner all lonely.

If I uncomment the block, however, none of those steps run. Instead, I get an SQLiteException: "no such table: seasons: , while compiling: SELECT _key FROM seasons"

Why don't steps 1-5 occur? Why does it jump ahead and try to compile that query before I'm ready for it? And how do I prevent this and force it to execute in sequence?

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that the Dialog box you create does not block the rest of the method, so you're still trying to populate the spinner before the user can tell the application (through the dialog box) to create the database.

Comment: A solid guess. I'll probably pull the database check into a separate activity.